# Trigger draw(rect) function

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, dataflow

In my app I have a chart into an UIView. 
This chart is drawed using `override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {}`.
Trouble is that datas to populate the chart comes from the ViewController which contains the UIView and they need some time to be calculated before being available for the chart.

Best thing would to launch draw(rect) code after datas calculation but I can't trigger this action, which run when UIView appear so I can't find a way to draw this chart with my datas, how can I do that?

Comment: You can call `setNeedsDisplay` on it to tell it that it needs to be redrawn

Comment: Trouble is on launch when chart get drew but there aren't datas to do that so app crash.

Comment: Well that's a completely different issue then the one in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried calling setNeedsDisplay() on the view when you are ready, that should trigger the drawing.